# Expression for Taylor's formula with a remainder

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, polynomials

Assume $f$ has a continuous second derivative $f~''$ in some neighborhood of $a$.Then, for every $x$ in this neighborhood, we have $f(x) = f(a) + f~'(a)(x-a) + E_1(x)$ , where

$E_1(x) = \int_a^x (x-t)f~''(t)dt$

**Derivation**: $E_1(x) = f(x)-f(a) - f~'(a)(x-a) = \int_a^x f~'(t)dt - f~'(a)\int_a^x dt = \int_a^x[f'(t)-f'(a)]dt$

Using integration by parts ( take $u = f~'(t)-f~'(a) , dv =dt= d(t-x)$, we get :

$E_1(x) = \int_a^x (x-t)f~''(t)dt$.

My problem is that in this proof, why should $f$ have a continuous second derivative? It doesn't seem that the continuous property of $f~''$ has been used anywhere.

> What happens when $f~''$ is discontinuous? Should there be any problem as certain discontinuous functions are still integrable?

Thank you for your help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You want $f$ to have a continuous second derivative so that $(x - t)f''(t)$ will be integrable over $[a,x]$ for every $x$. Then $E_1$ will make sense.

If $f''$ is discontinuous, say, at finitely many points, the result is still valid. More generally, if $f''$ is Riemann integrable, the integration by parts formula you used in the proof will remain valid.

Comment: But discontinuous functions can also be integrated?

Comment: @Wanderer not all of them.

Comment: Could you explain a little more? I mean, $E1$ will be always defined when $f~''$ is continuous. Is it just to say it with certainity that $E_1$ will be defined?

Comment: Yes, you need that certainty. It is also needed for you to do integration by parts.

Answer (score 0):

It guarantees that $(x-t)f''(t)$ is integrable, and that the fundamental theorem of calculus is applicable to it. Usually the statement of the fundamental theorem of calculus is limited to cases of a continuous integrand to avoid difficulties.

EDIT: More precisely, what's important is that in the proof of the integration by parts formula, the FTC should be applicable to $(t-x)(f'(t) - f'(a))$ and its derivative.

EDIT: In response to the new version: As long as $f''$ is integrable, the FTC will apply. However, it might be a more elaborate version of the FTC than that stated in your book.

Comment: Oh okay. From what I understand, this condition is just to ensure that the expression can be integrable. Although, there are discontinuous functions which are integrable, we chose $f~''$ to be continuous just to be on the safer side. Is this correct?

Comment: It depends on the exact statement of the fundamental theorem of calculus that you have at your disposal. Most likely, that is the reason, however.

Comment: okay, so the first fundamental theorem of calculus says that if $A(x) =\int_a^x f(x) dx,$ then $A~'(x)$ exists for all those points where $f(x)$ is continuous. Could you please explain with respect to this statement?

Comment: The integration by parts formula is $u(x)v(x) - u(a)v(a) = \int_a^x (uv)'(t) \, dt = \int_a^x u'(t)v(t) \, dt + \int_a^x u(t)v'(t) \, dt$. For it to be applicable, you need to know that the FTC is applicable to $uv$. In its most basic form, the FTC requires $(uv)'$ to be continuous. In terms of your statement, $f(t) = (uv)'(t)$. Then the conclusion $A'(x) = (uv)'(x)$ shows that $A(x)$ and $u(x)v(x)$ differ by a constant, and since $A(a) = 0$, we must have $A(x) = u(x)v(x) - u(a)v(a)$.